# eBPF map type array for storing the timestamps of packets

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I have defined a map named timestamp_map of type 'BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY' in my eBPF program

```
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
    __type(key, int);
    __type(value, uint64_t);
} timestamp_map SEC(".maps");
```

After processing some packets, I want to get the timestamps of packets that are processed. I used the command `sudo bpftool map dump <map ID>` to dump the details that are stored in the map timestamp_map. And I got

```
[{
        "key": 0,
        "values": [{
                "cpu": 0,
                "value": 287032432816
            },{
                "cpu": 1,
                "value": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'am getting a single value of timestamp and came to know that it was the timestamp of last packet that processed.

How to get the timestamp values of all packets that are processed. Should I use different type of array?

Comment: How many such packets would you like to timestamp? No map will be able to hold an infinity of packet timestamps. Did you consider sending those timestamps directly to a userspace program via a ring buffer map?

Comment: My intention was to get the timestamps of every packet when I dump the timestamp_map. I want to know is there any alternative to perCPU_array so that I can achieve above goal. And number of packets I like to timestamp is definitely not infinity but varies from 1000 to 10,000. And no I didn't consider sending those timestamps to userspace program via a ring buffer map.

Comment: If you're planning to compute a histogram of latencies or similar, I would do it in kernel space to only send the aggregated data. If you want all the timestamps, you could create a big `BPF_MAP_TYPE_STACK` and just push all timestamps to it. If you don't mind some extra overhead, you could send to userspace via a ring buffer.

Answer (score 0):

We need more context to provide a better answer. I can think of two solutions:

1. Consider increasing the max_entries. Seems the max entries is set to 1. and values may be overwritten. Try increasing the value to 1024 and see whether it helps?

   ```
   struct {
   __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
   __uint(max_entries, 1024);
   __type(key, int);
   __type(value, uint64_t);
   ```

   } timestamp_map SEC(".maps");

Have a look at the sample code in the kernel documentation:
https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/map_array.html#bpf-map-type-array

2. Check your keys and make sure they are unique, so you don't accidentally overwrite/update the values.